# SwiftUI - Save status when language is selected

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have successfully displayed the language in the UI, but I have a problem: when I click the "Save" button it still doesn't save the language I selected.

I want when I have selected the language and clicked the Save Button , it will return to the previous page and when I click it again it will show the language I selected before.

Above data is simulation only, I mainly focus on its features

All my current code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var language: String? = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            HStack {
                NavigationLink(destination:LanguageView(language: language)) {
                    Text("Language")
                        .padding()
                    Spacer()
                    Text(language!)
                        .padding()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct LanguageView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var pres
    @State var language: String?
    @State var selectedLanguage: String? = ""
    
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            CustomLanguageView(selectedLanguage: $language)
            
            Button(action: {
                language = selectedLanguage
                pres.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            })
            {
                Text("Save")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
            .padding()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
struct CustomLanguageView: View {
    var language = ["US", "English", "Mexico", "Canada"]
    @Binding var selectedLanguage: String?
    var body: some View {
        LazyVStack {
            ForEach(language, id: \.self) { item in
                SelectionCell(language: item, selectedLanguage: self.$selectedLanguage)
                    .padding(.trailing,40)
                Rectangle().fill(Color.gray)
                    .frame( height: 1,alignment: .bottom)
            }
            .frame(height:15)
        }
    }
}

struct SelectionCell: View {
    let language: String
    @Binding var selectedLanguage: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(language)
            Spacer()
            if language == selectedLanguage {
                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width:20, height: 15)
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            self.selectedLanguage = self.language
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Working for me. iOS 15, Xcode 13.1RC. By the way, those are mostly countries, not languages...

Comment: @Yrb Above data is simulation only, I mainly focus on its features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit to my previous answer, since something is blocking my edit to my previous answer, this one shows all the code I used to make it works well for me:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var language: String? = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            HStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: LanguageView(language: $language)) {
                    Text("Language").padding()
                    Spacer()
                    Text(language!).padding()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LanguageView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var pres
    @Binding var language: String?
 
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomLanguageView(selectedLanguage: $language) // <--- here
            Button(action: { pres.wrappedValue.dismiss() }) {  // <--- here
                Text("Save").foregroundColor(.black)
            }.padding()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct CustomLanguageView: View {
    var language = ["US", "English", "Mexico", "Canada"]
    @Binding var selectedLanguage: String?
    var body: some View {
        LazyVStack {
            ForEach(language, id: \.self) { item in
                SelectionCell(language: item, selectedLanguage: self.$selectedLanguage).padding(.trailing,40)
                Rectangle().fill(Color.gray).frame( height: 1,alignment: .bottom)
            }.frame(height:15)
        }
    }
}

struct SelectionCell: View {
    let language: String
    @Binding var selectedLanguage: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(language)
            Spacer()
            if language == selectedLanguage {
                Image(systemName: "checkmark").resizable().frame(width:20, height: 15)
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            self.selectedLanguage = self.language
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for everything. it worked fine for me

Comment: If I want to click again, will it change the color of the language I selected earlier?

Comment: if you want to change the color of the selected language text do this:

in `SelectionCell` add the `foregroundColor`, such as: 
`Text(language).foregroundColor((language == selectedLanguage) ? Color.red : Color.black)`

Comment: But when I tap on another color it changes again. I want it to stay the same color if I click on another language

Comment: I have updated the image in your 2nd answer

Comment: I don't understand what you want. You want to change the tick mark color, or the language text color, or both?  PS don't put images in my answer, do it in your question.

Comment: i want to change the color of the language text . I have updated the image to my question

Comment: when I first select language and when I click again it changes color to Gray, and when I continue to select another language Gray color it doesn't change color.

Comment: It is best if you ask a specific question regarding your selection issue.
In the mean time I suggest you study up on `@StateObject` and how 
to pass it around using `@EnvironmentObject`. You will more than likely 
have to use them to address your selection colors.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `@State var language` throughout and use `dismiss`, such as this,
to achieve what you want:

```
struct LanguageView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss  // <--- here
    @Binding var language: String?
 
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomLanguageView(selectedLanguage: $language) // <--- here
            
            Button(action: {
                dismiss()   // <--- here
            })
            {
                Text("Save").foregroundColor(.black)
            }
            .padding()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But when i click again it still wont checkmark the language i selected before

Comment: works very well for me on macos 12.01, xcode 13.1, targets ios 15 and macCatalyst 12.
Tested on mac Monterey and iPhone ios 15 devices. Maybe different on older systems. The checkmark is still there for me.

Comment: I'm getting the above error, can you take a look at it for me?

Comment: I've used @Environment(\.presentationMode) var pres . But when clicking again n still does not show the previously selected language checkmark. I have updated the code above

Comment: you are not following my advice here. Do not use `selectedLanguage`, try using `CustomLanguageView(selectedLanguage: $language)`as in my answer.

Comment: I have updated the code above. it still doesn't meet my needs

Comment: I've made a new answer. Could you explain what exactly is not meeting your needs. Does running my code  (2nd answer) gives you errors?